# Can you vertically center an element between two other elements with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to implement a design from our UX team that I'm having trouble with. Essentially, we have a fixed height header, a body area that takes up the rest of the screen, a piece of content that sits in the dead center of that body area, and a headline that is supposed to be centered between the header and the top of the content. I've made a codepen to demonstrate the idea:

http://codepen.io/nseegmiller/pen/EmgCI/

I'm having good success using `display: table[|-row|-cell]` to do things like fill up the remaining vertical space on a page, so my demo uses that. I'm not tied to that idea, but it works well for the majority of our UX designs. Everything here works great except actually getting that headline to sit between the content and the header. I've created a solution that uses JavaScript to find the top of the content block and absolutely position the headline, but it doesn't work as cleanly as a pure CSS solution would be. Anyway to do this with pure CSS? I'm only supporting IE9+ and most recent 3 versions of other browsers, so I can use most "modern" techniques.

Comment: Is there a reason that your headline html is outside the `.background` div that wraps the rest of the html?

Comment: I'd say: Punish the UX team. ;-P

Comment: Is it possible to restructure your html?

Comment: you mean like this? http://codepen.io/Nico_O/pen/dxhsk

Comment: @MattDiamant - just because I was trying to build a quick code pen demo. It can go anywhere. I have full control over the html structure. I was just trying to demonstrate what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: @NicoO - No. The headline is not vertically centered between the header and the content there, it rides closer to the content.

Comment: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: I have to agree with @Quentin - outside of using javascript, the only pure CSS solution is to use flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to position the `center-above` mid way between the header and the box in the middle of the page, change your `.center-above` class to this:

```
.center-above {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Since the height of `center-above` is variable, it won't work. If it has a height of 300px for example, it would need a `margin-top: -150px;` to be vertically centered. But since this is variable, we can't declare it in the css.

Comment: Correct. If the center gets taller, this fails to work properly. As shown in this codepen fork: http://codepen.io/nseegmiller/pen/lyeLb

Answer (score 0):

How is this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rgnsh

I divided the main-body in 3 divs and used `table-row` and `table-cell` to vertically center the content.

```
.main-body {  
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.tablerow{
  display: table-row;
  height: 33%;
}

.tablecell{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: That works great as long as the center content block is <33% of the total in height. If you add a lot of content to the center block, the headline then takes up too much space and the content block is no longer centered.

Answer (score 0):

I think it does not go without a little bit of JS

Look at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/pHctJ/)

#### HTML

```
<div class="top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic labore facilis ad harum eos a non autem deserunt dolore. Architecto.
</div>
<div class="middle">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-wrap" id="header-wrap">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="header-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste adipisci sequi ullam quasi illo reprehenderit consequuntur nobis omnis sunt minus .
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrap" id="content-wrap">
      <div class="content" id="content">
        <div class="content-inner" id="content-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.top {
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
}
.middle {
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 40px;
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.header-wrap ,
.content-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.header-wrap {
  bottom: auto;
  height: 50%;
}
.header,
.content {
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

#### JS

```
window.onload = window.onresize = function() {
  document.getElementById('header-wrap').style.height = document.getElementById('content-inner').offsetTop + 'px'
}
```

Comment: I have to agree.  The only other way to do this without any javascript is to use flexbox which has limited and complicated browser support.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. As I mentioned, I got it working with similarly JS to what you posted, but I was really hoping to find a pure CSS solution.

Comment: Yes flexbox would be an alternative. If it had the browser support.